# Fixed size cell surrounded by two others with border

Tags: html, css, web

I need to create a table of the following characteristics:

__*_*__*_*__ 100% of the window width ***_*__*_*__*_*_**

|  auto width  |  860 px width, border  |  auto width, border

---

So in other words: a centered cell of 860px surrounded by one other cell on each side. The right cell also has to have a border set.

I can't come up with something friendly to all (even old IE6) browsers. The compatibility is important for me. I don't really care if it's table or a bunch of divs. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this very quirksmode markup, but it looks like it does what you've described:

Edited: added table-layout:fixed for table and width="860" for the central td:

```
<style type="text/css">
table{ table-layout: fixed; }
.w860{ width:858px; }
.brdr{ border-style:dashed; border-width:1px; }
.td860{ background-color:#eee; }
</style>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td width="860" class="td860">
        <div class="w860 brdr">
            content
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="brdr"> also some content</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Tested in FF, IE6+ (quirksmode and standards), Safari for windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
table{
width:100%;
}
 .auto{
width:auto;
}
.fixed{
width:860px;
}
.bordered{
border: 1px #ff0000 dashed;
}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="auto">11&nbsp;</td>
<td class="fixed">111&nbsp;</td>
<td class="auto bordered">111&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```